# Aboud flash download

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, file, flex4, download

I am using download functionality of AS3 to download a wav file from given http adress and save it to other location. However the file beign downloaded is 1.03 MB but the file that is downloaded is only 655 bytes :) . I used the sample code from the adobe page for FileReference class [FileReference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#download%28%29) so I dont have prolem with the code itself.

Any idea why the download is working bad, i.e i get only 655 bytes out of 1 MB file?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vlad, open the 655 byte file with a text editor for more clues.

Regards

Comment: Good suggestion, it may very well contain HTML from a 404-page or something like that.

Comment: Yup it is html contents. I get the listing of the folder in which the wav folder resides, as when apache lists contents of given folder. Any idea why it is doing this?

Comment: I found what was the error, I was adding the url witout the file name on its end. So althought the download() function accepts the file name as a second parameter it must be also in the URLRequest url. Now it works